# Centos 7.3 Quagga (ospf) configuration changes after reboot

Tags: linux-networking, centos7, ospf, quagga

I have configured ospf as shown below:

cat /etc/quagga/ospfd.conf

```
!
! Zebra configuration saved from vty
!   2017/05/31 10:13:20
!
...
...
...
!
interface foo1
 description Tunnel foo1
 ip ospf cost 250
 ip ospf dead-interval minimal hello-multiplier 4
!
router ospf
 ospf router-id 10.0.0.1
 log-adjacency-changes
 compatible rfc1583
 timers throttle spf 200 400 10000
 redistribute kernel
 network 10.0.0.0./24 area 0.0.0.1
 network 192.168.0.0/16 area 0.0.0.0
!
line vty
!
```

After finishing my configuration and saving it, ospf works fine, configuration is saved in /etc/quagga/ospfd.conf.

The problem is when i reboot my machine (it is a vps) the configuration file hasn't changed but quagga configuration has. When i enter with telnet in port 2604, and type 'show running config', it shows me this:

```
ospfd# show running-config

Current configuration:
!
...
...
...
!
interface foo1
 description Tunel foo1
 ip ospf network broadcast
 ip ospf cost 250
 ip ospf dead-interval minimal hello-multiplier 4
!
router ospf
 ospf router-id 10.0.0.1
 log-adjacency-changes
 compatible rfc1583
 timers throttle spf 200 400 10000
 redistribute kernel
 network 10.0.0.0./24 area 0.0.0.1
 network 192.168.0.0/16 area 0.0.0.0
!
line vty
```

As you can see, the topology changed **from point-to-point to broadcast**. So i have to manually change the ip ospf network to point-to-point after each reboot.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you use the "write" command to save your configuration?